# Animating active object issue in motion tracking project

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, motion-capture

Why won't my 'meteorite' continue forward follow-thru even though set as an active object in the Physics tab?

• Project for school - to VFX a meteorite striking building
• Must finish by this coming Sunday night! (3/21) if at all possible
• Using Blender v2.83 on desktop PC with Windows 10 - Blender version is what school uses
• Any / all help welcomed :D

Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Animated” is checked. The sphere will follow its animated coordinates when this is checked. If it becomes checked after the sphere has physic-ed around, it will snap back to those coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @CrystalKaulbars Ur welcome, TYL I just discovered this the day 